# How can I add an int to a char in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to add an int to each char in a char array but I don't know how to do that.

```
void Offset(char sirDeCaractere[100], int x)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (sirDeCaractere[i] != '\0')
    {
        sirDeCaractere[i] += x;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%c", sirDeCaractere[i]);
}
```

I've been trying to do something like this for a while, but I can't figure it out.
Written like this I don't think it will work due to pointer arithmetic, but I have no other ideas.

For example:

```
Input:
sirDeCaractere = cuvant
x = 5
Output:
hz{fsy
```

How should I edit my code in order to achieve the desired output?

Right now my program is crashing (as I said, because sirDeCaractere[i] += x; is pointer arithmetic).

Thanks.

Comment: Please show a complete [mre].

Comment: Your logic is confusing: `'c' + 3` is `'f'`, but you want `'h'`?

Comment: I don't understand how your input `cuvant` is related to the output `hz{fsy`. `sirDeCaractere[i] += x` is n ot pointer arithmetic. The code you show looks more or less correct, but `printf("%c", sirDeCaractere[i]);` makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I'm sorry. I wrote x = 3 instead of x = 5. That was a typo

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu [edit] and correct.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I did. Sorry.

Comment: Switch from `printf("%c", sirDeCaractere[i]);` to `printf("%s\n", sirDeCaractere);`  and you are done.

Comment: @DavidRanieri It's crashing. And if I use the debugger I get "Access violation writing on sirDeCaractere[i] += x;"

Comment: Sorry but what is the goal of the function ?? Can you give an example before/after ??

Comment: Then the problem is in the code you are not showing, how do you flll and pass `sirDeCaractere`?

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu Do you pass this function a pointer to a string literal? If so, that's your problem. Literals are constants and this function modifies the thing it is passed a pointer to. You can't modify a constant because it's ... constant.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes. That's what I did. I understand now and you're completely right. If you want, you can add your answer, I will accept it because it was the most relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Offset(char sirDeCaractere[100], int x)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (sirDeCaractere[i] != '\0')
    {
        sirDeCaractere[i] += x;
        i++;
    }
    // remove this line, it makes no sense    printf("%c", sirDeCaractere[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
   char test[] = "ABCD";
   Offset(test, 1);
   printf("%s\n", test);
}
```

Output:

```
BCDE
```

I guess the code you didn't show is something like this:

```
...
char *test = "ABCD";
Offset(test, 1);
...
```

or

```
Offset("ABCD", 1);
```

which will crash on most platforms. Read this form more information: [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a "char *s" initialized with a string literal, but not "char s[]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a)

**Bonus:**

Be aware that the `[100]` below is useless:

```
void Offset(char sirDeCaractere[100], int x)
```

you can write:

```
void Offset(char sirDeCaractere[], int x)
```

or :

```
void Offset(char *sirDeCaractere, int x)
```

which do *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: My code looked like this: https://pastebin.com/h54W0NTg

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66273647/edit) the question and show your code _there_.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu `Offset("test", 3);` has the exact problem I described in the answer.